# How to validate a new questionnaire with all ordinal variables and one binary?

Tags: validation, pca, hl7-fhir, items

I have to validate a questionnaire where all items assume an ordinal response and only one assumes a dichotomous response. How do I validate the questionnaire in this context? If I have to do an exploratory factor analysis, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The items in the QuestionnaireResponse will each have a linkId that identifies the corresponding item in the Questionnaire.  You then check the answer for that response item against the rules for the question item.  So the ordinal items will have a type of 'choice' and the binary item will presumably have a type of attachment.  Your validation process will check that the answers have the appropriate type - and meet any other constraints, such as falling within the allowed list of values, having the right attachment mime type, having an appropriate binary size, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I did not understand what you mean and how to proceed operationally

Comment: Perhaps flesh out your question to better explain what you're trying to do and where you're running into trouble?  I can then update my response.